# How to link to a custom php page on a Wordpress Admin Plugin?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-admin

I am quite new in wordpress dev and I am writing an Admin plugin to handle certificate creation.
I achieve to create the plugin, and I have it in the Admin Menu via the add_menu_page.

Here is the plugin concept:

- I used the WP_List_Table to display the list of users.
- I have added custom columns with some user meta-data.
- I have added a custom column with a button.
  This button should display a form (with the correct items data to create a certificate. this form is designed in the file test.php. (Exactly the same way the edit user link is acting).

What I would like to do is :
**I would like my button to open another php page that contains a Form and process that forms. And After go back to the previous page. More or less the same way the Users Admin do with the Users-edit.php page.**

My plugin name is gbr-certificate.

My issues :

I don't know how to link to my php page that contains the form (test.php). This files is in my plugin root directory.
I have tried :

1. hard coding the url : In the column_default function adding the following code for the button :

```php
$link = "http://localhost:8888/Standard/wp_content/plugins/gbr-certificate/test.php?user-id=" . $item->ID . "&wp_http_referer=" . urlencode( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));

$btn = "<button id=\"cert-\" class=\"button\" href=\"" . $link . "\">create cert.</button>";
```

Result: I have the right links in my button `href` :

```
<button id="cert-" class="button" href="http://localhost:8888/Standard/wp_content/plugins/gbr-certificate/test.php?user-id=1&amp;wp_http_referer=%2FStandard%2Fwp-admin%2Fadmin.php%3Fpage%3Duser-cert-manager">create cert.</button>
```

But when i Click it => i get to the following url :

> http://localhost:8888/Standard/wp-admin/admin.php?s=&_wpnonce=feb9b81efe&_wp_http_referer=%2FStandard%2Fwp-admin%2Fadmin.php%3Fpage%3Duser-cert-manager&paged=1

with a blank page displayed.

Could someone help me to achieve this ?

Thanks.
Guillaume B.

Comment: use echo plugins_url('gbr-certificate')."test.php?user-id=" . $item->ID . "&wp_http_referer=" . urlencode( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));

 function
example link : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_url/

Comment: hello, still not working. I have made some debug. when I have your solution I get the link string correct : http://localhost:8888/Standard/wp-content/plugins/user-certificate/test.php?user-id=1&amp;wp_http_referer=%2FStandard%2Fwp-admin%2Fadmin.php%3Fpage%3Duser-cert-manager. but when I click on the button I go to a blank page with the changed url : http://localhost:8888/Standard/wp-admin/admin.php?s=&_wpnonce=977a281259&_wp_http_referer=%2FStandard%2Fwp-admin%2Fadmin.php%3Fpage%3Duser-cert-manager&paged=1.